# search option for dependent tkinter combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, search, combobox

I have a JSON file which has data in code-name pairs. I made dependent comboboxes to automatically update the name when the code is selected. I have successfully implemented the dependent combobox code, and I want to implement a search option for the code combobox. Can someone please help me in how to implement this?

```py
def checkkey(event): 
       
    value = event.widget.get() 
    print(value) 
      
    # get data from l 
    if value == '': 
        data = l 
    else: 
        data = [] 
        for item in l: 
            if value.lower() in item.lower(): 
                data.append(item)
```

I tried to add this search function to my code, but this code is to read a list which doesn't have a key-value pair. I want to know how to do it for a list that looks kind of like this:

```py
{ 'code':'name', 'code':'name', 'code':'name'}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  `l` is a dictionary, but `data` is to be a list (based on your code), so why do you assign `l` (dictionary) to `data` (list) when `value == ''`?

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] with sample data of `l`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.